# Problemas al pasar parametros por ruta laravel

Tags: laravel, api, eloquent, controller, parametros

he estado de distintas formas solucionar un problema pero aun no he podido, estoy consumiendo una api en laravel en donde quiero hacer un filtro con varios parametros opcionales

**El problema** es que en mi funcion cuando recibo los parametros y quiero hacer mi consulta usando eloquen me dice que los parametros son indefinido

Aca esta el endpoint que consulto y como envio los parametros

```
avisos/titulo/ejemplo/ubicacion/320/estado/2/categoria/3
```

En mi archivo de rutas api

```
Route::get('avisos/titulo/{titulo?}/ubicacion/{ubicacion?}/estado/{estado?}/categoria/{categoria?}', [AvisosController::class, 'prueba']);
```

aca mi controlador y funcion que se ejecuta

```
public function prueba($titulo="",$ubicacion=0,$estado=0,$categoria=0){
        //$ubicacionRecibida = $ubicacion;
        //Cuando retorno de esta formas las variables tienen contenido
        // return response()->json([
        //     'titulo' => $titulo,
        //     'categoria' => $categoria,
        //     'ubicacion' => $ubicacion,
        //     'estado' => $estado
        // ], Response::HTTP_OK); 
        
        //Pero al intentar usarla en mi consulta la variable es undefined
        $avisos = new Avisos();
        $avisos =  Avisos::select(
            'Avisos.id',
            'Avisos.titulo',
            'Avisos.descripcion',
            'Avisos.imagen',
            'Avisos.created_at as fecha',
            'Avisos.vistas',
            'users.name',
            'users.id as idUsuario',
            'comunas.nombreComuna',
            'ciudads.nombreCiudad'
            )->join('categorias','categorias.id', '=','avisos.idCategoria')
            ->join('users','users.id', '=','avisos.idUsuario')
            ->join('comunas','comunas.id','=','avisos.idComuna')
            ->join('ciudads', 'ciudads.id','=','comunas.idCiudad')
            ->with('valoraciones')
            ->when($ubicacion, function ($query) {
                $query->where('avisos.idComuna','=',$ubicacion);#aca es undefined linea 250
            })
            ->get();



            // ->when($categoria, function ($query) {
            //     $query->where('avisos.idCategoria','=',2);
            // })->when($estado, function ($query) {
            //     $query->where('avisos.idEstado','=',1);
            // })
            return $avisos;
    }
```

El error que recibo

```
ErrorException: Undefined variable $ubicacion in file C:\.....\app\Http\Controllers\V1\AvisosController.php on line 250
```

Los parametros llegan bien al controlador, de hecho si hago un `return $parametro;` lo retorna correctamente el **el problema es cuando lo intento usar en mi consulta, me dice que es undefined**, y me pasa con todos los demas parametros (estado, categoria,ubicacion, titulo.

Ojala alguien haya pasado por esto antes y me informe si me falta algo por realizar o de que otra forma puedo intentarlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

despues de intentar distintas soluciones, realmente era algo sumamente sencillo:

Despues de analizar mas a detalle, me di cuenta que debo pasarle el parametro a la funcion, y quedaria de la siguiente forma:

```
->when($ubicacion, function ($query, $ubicacion) {#Aca le paso el parametro a la funcion
    $query->where('avisos.idComuna','=',intval($ubicacion));
})
```

Espero que sirva para la posteridad.